# AngularJS Duplicate key array in a repeater

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi currently i´m programming a application in AngularJs with api rest, but there is something that i miss.

Customers can create organizations with their branchoffices. To create and show the organizations and branchoffices i use the code below.

when the user create an organization there isn´t any problem, but when the user create the second one, the code update the first entry and generate as second one with the same value. so you hava a duplicate key.

What i´m doing wrong?

below you can see the code and pictures attached

First time introduce data and send api, but second time appear the same text. I introduce the new value and send to api rest, and api answer with a right values, but myorganizations variable has the duplicate key with the new value.

**First time**
[image: Modal Organizations First Time]

**Second time**
[image: Modal Organizations Second Time]
**Results**
[image: Results after push in myorganizations variable]

**HTML File**

```
<div class="row">
    <h4>Mis Organizaciones  <a href=""  type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#organizationModal"><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></small></a></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="organization in myorganizations.data">
    <h5>{{organization.company_name}}</h5>
    <div ng-repeat="branch in organization.branches">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <a ui-sref="mybranchoffice({name: '{{branch.branch_name}}', id: '{{branch.branch_id}}', company_id: '{{organization.company_id}}'})">
          <div class="thumbnail-organization" style="background: url({{branch.branch_image_url}}) center center no-repeat;"></div>
          </a>
          <div class="caption">
            <h6 class="thumbnail-organization-name"></h6>
          </div>        
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="clearfix visible-sm" ng-if="($index+1)%2==0"></div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md" ng-if="($index+1)%3==0"></div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-lg" ng-if="($index+1)%4==0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <a  type="button" href="" data-company="{{organization.company_id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#branchModal">Create new Branch</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <a  type="button" href=""  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#organizationModal" >Create new Organization</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
    $scope.newOrganization = function () {
        butlerService.createOrganization($scope.organization).then(function(neworganization){
            console.log(neworganization);
            tmp.data[0].company_id = neworganization.data.company_id;
            tmp.data[0].company_name = neworganization.data.company_name;
            tmp.data[0].branches=[];
            console.log(tmp);
            $scope.myorganizations.data.push(tmp.data[0]);
            console.log($scope.myorganizations);
        }), function (error){

        }
    }
```

**Service**

```
createOrganization: function (organization) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: "post",
                url: urlCreateOrganization,
                data: organization
            })
            .success(function(response){
                deferred.resolve(response);
            })
            .error(function(err){
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your variable init it is hard to say for sure, but it seems that here:

```
        tmp.data[0].company_id = neworganization.data.company_id;
        tmp.data[0].company_name = neworganization.data.company_name;
        tmp.data[0].branches=[];
```

you are rewriting over the first element in your array. And here:

```
$scope.myorganizations.data.push(tmp.data[0]);
```

You are pushing once more the same reference to variable in an array.

Just create new variable before you assign values to it and before you push it in the array.
Something like this:

```
var tmp = {};
tmp.company_id = neworganization.data.company_id;
tmp.company_name = neworganization.data.company_name;
tmp.branches=[];
console.log(tmp);
$scope.myorganizations.data.push(tmp);
```

FYI http returns promisse, you don't have to wrap it once more.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry if my question is easy, but i started to program 4 months ago and i have a lot of doubts yet.  this is my variable init 'var tmp = {data:[{company_id:"", company_name:"", branches:[]}]}', and i can´t understand if i rewrite my tmp variable althout will be an array  and after pushing in the second time update and push the new value. it is like execute two times this line '$scope.myorganizations.data.push(tmp);'

Comment: Respect to promisse, i don´t know what does you mean? it´s possible i don´t need use de $q Service. how did you do this?

Comment: In service you can simply return $http.post(urlCreateOrganization, organization) And controller stays the same in your case.

Comment: Ok, i understand you, you want to say the $q service is not neccesary, isn´t it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: in simple cases - yes